# Visual Studio 2013/TFS: Work in one style, commit in another?

Tags: visual-studio, tfs, visual-studio-2013, coding-style

I was wondering if there was a way to make it so when I checkout a file, it formats to my Visual Studio style, but it formats back to the custom style right before a check in (note that either style can be configured in Visual Studio, but I only know how to configure one at a time).  I would like to automate this, but even the ability to have Visual Studio remember two different styles that I could manually switch would help some (for example, CTRL-K CTRL-D for style 1, CTRL-K CTRL-E for style 2).

So far research has only turned up serverside event handlers for TFS, but I'm wanting a 'on my desktop' solution.

Worst case scenario I'll take a shot at writing my own VS extension, but this is one of those 'I can't be the first person who wanted to do this' moments.

Comment: The closest I could find related to your requirement is Rebracer. But this is a per Solution setting, not multiple setting for the same solution. Thought it would be of some help, https://github.com/SLaks/Rebracer

Answer (score 1):

So I've worked out a partial solution.  This isn't nice or pretty, but it is a decent starting point for anyone with a similar desire.  I hope to improve it in the future.

First, set up style 1 in Visual Studio the normal way so CTRL-K, CTRL-D formats it into style 1.

Second, download and install the software to make a Visual Studio Extension.  [Here](http://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/explore/explore-vside-vsi.aspx) is the basic guide for it.

Third, create a standard out of the box VSPackage for a menu command.  [Here](http://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/explore/explore-vside-vsi.aspx) is the basics.

Fourth, in the code that is created, in the MenuItemCallback, add the following.  This sets up a custom function (editFiles in the example) to run on check in.  Note, this required you to be looking at the Pending Changes page of Team Explorer when you click your menu item (I plan to make this work without having to do such).

```
ITeamExplorer teamExplorer = (ITeamExplorer)this.GetService(typeof(ITeamExplorer));

if(teamExplorer != null)
{
    if(teamExplorer.CurrentPage != null && teamExplorer.CurrentPage.GetType().ToString() == "Microsoft.VisualStudio.TeamFoundation.VersionControl.PendingChanges.PendingChangesPageVS")
    {
        if (teamExplorer.CurrentPage.PageContent != null)
        {
            Type pendingChangesPageViewType = teamExplorer.CurrentPage.PageContent.GetType();
            FieldInfo field = pendingChangesPageViewType.GetField("checkinButton", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.GetField | BindingFlags.Instance);
            System.Windows.Controls.Button checkinButton = (System.Windows.Controls.Button)field.GetValue(teamExplorer.CurrentPage.PageContent);
            checkinButton.Click += new System.Windows.RoutedEventHandler(editFiles);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        IVsUIShell uiShell = (IVsUIShell)GetService(typeof(SVsUIShell));
        Guid clsid = Guid.Empty;
        int result;
        Microsoft.VisualStudio.ErrorHandler.ThrowOnFailure(uiShell.ShowMessageBox(
                0,
                ref clsid,
                "VSPTest01",
                string.Format(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, "This function only works on the Pending Changes page of Team Explorer."),
                string.Empty,
                0,
                OLEMSGBUTTON.OLEMSGBUTTON_OK,
                OLEMSGDEFBUTTON.OLEMSGDEFBUTTON_FIRST,
                OLEMSGICON.OLEMSGICON_INFO,
                0,        // false
                out result));
    }
}
```

Fifth, in the same class that the MenuItemCallback is in, add the function being called on button click.

```
public void editFiles(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    EnvDTE.IVsExtensibility extensibility = GetService(typeof(EnvDTE.IVsExtensibility)) as EnvDTE.IVsExtensibility;
    EnvDTE80.DTE2 dte = extensibility.GetGlobalsObject(null).DTE as EnvDTE80.DTE2;

    VersionControlExt vce = dte.GetObject("Microsoft.VisualStudio.TeamFoundation.VersionControl.VersionControlExt") as VersionControlExt;

    foreach(var pendingChange in vce.PendingChanges.IncludedChanges)
    {
        string filePath = pendingChange.LocalItem;
        //Do your style changes here, file by file, however you would like.
        //Preferably have some styling software you call.
    }
}
```

Finally, add this VSPackage to your Visual Studio.

As I said, this is a rough solution that still needs some work.  I'll improve this once I've gotten it worked out.  And if someone knows of something better, please by all means answer this question with it.